# S3 API на клиенте или сервере?

Tags: amazon-s3, облачное-хранилище

Не могу понять алгоритм работы с S3 облаком. Есть контейнер, есть пользователь, есть Access Key и Secret Key. Так же имеется backend и клиентские приложения(android, ios, web). S3 облако используется не от AWS, сторонний хостер, но S3 подразумевает совместимый API.

Интересуют следующие вопросы:

1. Загрузка файлов в контейнер. Я думаю глупо и опасно сохранять Access/Secret Key на клиенте. Т.к. потеря этих ключей позволит злоумышленнику загружать неограниченное кол-во файлов в контейнер, что выльется в неконтролируемый рост расходов. Как правильно загружать файлы в S3? Единственное, что приходит в голову, это загрузка файла на backend, а оттуда уже в S3? Верный ли это подход? И если да, то это единственный сценарий использования S3?
2. Чтение файлов с контейнера. Ситуация та же: Access/Secret Key на клиенте позволят злоумышленнику атаковать на запросах и трафику (но подозреваю, что это не совсем рентабельно для атакующего). Объясню: изначально я так же планировал сперва скачивать файл на backend и потом отдавать клиенту, т.к. так я хотя бы могу контролировать частоту запросов с определенного ip. Но меня смущает то, что придется гонять трафик по схеме S3 -> backend -> client, кажется, что S3 был придуман как раз для разгрузки backend`а и отдачи контента по схеме S3 -> client.

Answer (score 0):

Вы правильно подметили, что давать клиенту секретные ключи нельзя. По-этому код доступа к s3 bucket должен находиться на сервере.
На счет зачем вообще тогда нужен s3? Ответ - это удобно, можешь хранить сколько угодно данных, ты не паришься за безопасность, за зжатие, контроль версий файлов и тп. Да, нужно серверное приложение которое будет доступаться к s3, но это не проблема

Comment: Меня смущает то, что придётся гонять трафик через сервер (мне кажется глупой идеей грузить 1Г на сервер, потом грузить его в s3, потом удалять его с сервера. Но давать ключи пока кажется еще более глупой затеей). Недавно наткнулся на подготовленные url. Т.е. как я понял, сервер генерирует какую то одноразовую ссылку для клиента. Пока копаю в эту сторону.